# how make animation in geoserver using "dimension"

Tags: animation, geoserver

I have one layer in geoserver. I would like make a time animation with this layer. I'm able to modify the "dimension" parameter. How can I visualize the animation after that I made this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very [detailed tutorial on how to use the GeoServer Animator](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/animreflector.html), basically you make a call to the animator endpoint:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/animate?layers=cite:ne_50m_coastline,cite:earthquakes
```

with your required layer(s) specified. For an actual animation you need to provide two more parameters:

aparam - the value to change
   avalues - the values to set aparam to for each frame.

so in the following:

```
aparam=time&avalues=1900,%201901,%201902,%201903,%201904
```

I am setting the time dimension to 1900, then 1901, 1902 etc

this returns me an animated gif like this:

[image: USGS Earthquake catalog by decade from 1900]

(Though I had to use decades here as by year is too big to upload to stackoverflow).